# Process.env not reading? Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, environment-variables, multer

I'm trying to set my Amazon AWS access key and secret by using multer:

```
var upload = multer({
secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_SECRET,
accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
})
```

In my zshrc file I've done

```
export AWS_ACCESS_SECRET="mysecret"
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY="mykey"
```

however on running node, I get the error

```
 if (!opts.secretAccessKey) throw new Error('secretAccessKey is required')
```

However hardcoding the key and secret makes it work, but obviously that's not the safest way to go.

I have done source ~/.zshrc but it still is showing the error.

Comment: Can you see those two environment variables when you `console.log(process.env)` ?

Comment: In my node shell when I type process.env, it displays the access_key and secret

Comment: U can run it in the beginning or run it on a seperate file and then `node thatFile.js` , or open a node console with just writing `node` in the terminal. it should open a node shell where you can run that logging

Comment: In my node shell when I type process.env, it displays the access_key and secret

Comment: `opts` has those two as items in the object ?

Comment: Yes it's an object

Comment: There is something missing, I can see in your example that `upload` is an object of `multer` and it inserts the key/secret, but then the check is happening on a different object `opts` , if the items are in opts ; both key/secret, then this should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multer out of the box doesn't support s3. The way you're creating a new `multer` object is incorrect. The only available [options](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#multeropts) when creating a new `multer` object are `dest/storage`, `fileFilter` and `limits`.

If you want to use Multer with S3 directly, you can use [`multer-s3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3). With that you can pass in a new option `storage` that will take your `secretAccessKey` and your `accessKeyId`.

If you don't use `multer-s3` you can use `multer` with `aws-sdk`'s [`S3` Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html).

```
var multer = require('multer');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
var secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_SECRET;

var upload = multer({dest: '/temp'});       
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey
});
```